How can I render out a text from server actions nextjs?
New to Next.js
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();


export default function Home() {

  const test = async (formData: FormData) => {
    "use server";

    const firstName = formData.get("firstName");
    const lastName = formData.get("lastName");
    const email = formData.get("email");

    const alreadyExists = await prisma.test.findFirst({
      where: {
        email: email as string
      }
    });

    if (alreadyExists) {
      return {
        message: "User already exists"
      };
    } else {
      await prisma.test.create({
        data: {
          firstName: firstName as string,
          lastName: lastName as string,
          email: email as string
        }
      });
    }
}

  return (
    <form action={test}>
      <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="firstName" className="bg-black"/>
      <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="lastName" className="bg-black"/>
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" className="bg-black"/>
      <input type="submit"/>
      <p>{message}</p>
    </form>
  );
}


This is my code and I want to render out the message inside the if statment but I can't get it to work and I don't know how.
I tired useFormState but I could not get it to work.

Your message is not defined. try using useState or variable to catch that result.And if you would like to use useState, you have to turn Home into client component and extract test function out since it's a server action.
// test.ts
"use server";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

const test = async (formData: FormData) => {
  const firstName = formData.get("firstName");
  const lastName = formData.get("lastName");
  const email = formData.get("email");

  const alreadyExists = await prisma.test.findFirst({
    where: {
      email: email as string,
    },
  });

  if (alreadyExists) {
    return {
      message: "User already exists",
    };
  } else {
    await prisma.test.create({
      data: {
        firstName: firstName as string,
        lastName: lastName as string,
        email: email as string,
      },
    });
  }
};


// Home.tsx
"use client";
import { useState } from "react";
import { test } from "./test";

export default function Home() {
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState("");

  const submit = async (formData: FormData) => {
    const { message } = await test(formData);
    if (message) {
      setMsg(message);
    } else {
      // ...
    }
  };

  return (
    <form action={submit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="firstName"
        placeholder="firstName"
        className="bg-black"
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        name="lastName"
        placeholder="lastName"
        className="bg-black"
      />
      <input
        type="email"
        name="email"
        placeholder="email"
        className="bg-black"
      />
      <input type="submit" />
      <p>{msg}</p>
    </form>
  );
}

